# backed up mongo and now I'm an receiving authorization error

Tags: mongodb

I am running a very simple MongoDB install on Windows 10 and interacting with it via Node. I just used mongodump to create a backup, and now I'm getting this when I try to run the app I've been working on:

```
MongoError: not authorized on [db] to execute command ...
```

I've just been using the default config settings (authorization not enabled in the mongo.cfg) so I have no idea why the authorization suddenly wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check your connection string, anything got changed mistakenly.

Comment: @Mani It is connecting (I have a console.log in the callback confirming it) but refuses to execute any of the commands that were working earlier.

Comment: Check which database you are connecting to, may the user you are logging in doesn't have access to the database.

Comment: I never created any users for this database, and I just ran "show users" in the shell to make sure.